# Nuxt3 can't import component in tests

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vitest

I'm trying to run a component unit test on Nuxt 3 but I get an error telling me that the component cannot be found..

**FAIL  test/components/button.test.ts [ test/components/button.test.ts ]
Error: Failed to resolve import "@/components/Texts/Button/ButtonText.vue" from "components\Button\Button.vue". Does the file exist?**

`button.spec.ts`

```js
import {test, expect} from 'vitest';
import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import Button from "../../components/Button/Button.vue";

test('Button Component', async () => {
    const button = mount(Button, {
        props: {
            text: 'My Test Button'
        }
    });
    expect(button.text()).toEqual('My Test Button');
});
```

`Button.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="Button">
    <slot name="left" />
    <ButtonText :text="text" />
    <slot name="right" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'Button',
  components: {ButtonText},
  props: {
    // Text to display in the button
    text: {
      type: String as () => string,
      default: 'Button',
      required: true,
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that `@/components/Texts/Button/ButtonText.vue` actually exists, a solution to your problem might be adding aliases to your `./vitest.config.ts` like that:

```js
// vitest.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

import { aliases } from './aliases'

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: { aliases },
    // ... further settings
})
```

```js
// aliases.ts

import { resolve } from 'path';

const r = (p: string) => resolve(__dirname, p);

export const alias: Record<string, string> = {
    '~~': r('.'),
    '~~/': r('./'),
    '@@': r('.'),
    '@@/': r('./'),
    // ... other aliases
};
```